# How can I use Metatag Module to set specific tags on specific nodes?

Tags: meta-tags

I'm using the Metatag module to set tags on content generally throughout my project. But there is one group of content where I want to be able to set the metatags for specific nodes. Because these nodes have unique specific tags, I want to be able to set them at the node level.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Drupal 7**

When you configure Metatag, you can click on `+ Add default meta tags` and this will allow you to **set them up by Content Type**.

[image]

[image]

If you need to alter **only specific nodes**, edit your node and scroll down to the end and select the Meta tags Tab

[image]